# Get Value and Set Action from Branch.io Response (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I recently want my apps integrated with Deep Link, and I found that Branch.io is the best platform to do it. I successfully read my deep link URL. And here is my code for read it that I put in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()
branch.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, andRegisterDeepLinkHandler: {params, error in
    if error == nil {
        print("params: %@", params as? [String: AnyObject] ?? {})
        //Read Deep Link
        let sessionParams = Branch.getInstance().getLatestReferringParams()
        let installParams = Branch.getInstance().getFirstReferringParams()
        guard let data = params as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
        guard let options = data["promo_code"] as? String else { return }
        switch options {
        case "testing": self.window?.rootViewController?.present( ArticleViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Berhasil DeepLink")
        default: break
        }
    }
})
```

And here is the response that I got:

```
["$marketing_title": Paket Tour, 
"+is_first_session": 0, 
"$canonical_url": http://www.invisee.com, 
"~referring_link": https://invisee.app.link/promo?al_applink_da
ta=%7B%22target_url%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fitunes.apple.com%5C%2FWe
bObjects%5C%2FMZStore.woa%5C%2Fwa%5C%2FredirectToContent%3Fid%3D1401179128%22%2
C%22extras%22%3A%7B%22deeplink_context%22%3A%22%7B%5C%22promo_code%5C%22%3A%5C%2
2testing%5C%22%7D%22%7D%2C%22referer_app_link%22%3A%7B%22url%22%3A%22fb%3A%5C%2F
%5C%2F%5C%2F%22%2C%22app_name%22%3A%22Facebook%22%7D%7D, 
"+clicked_branch_link": 1, 
"$og_title": INVISEE | Investment is easy, 
"al_applink_data": 
    {"target_url":"https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/WebObjects\/MZStore.woa\/wa\/redirectToContent?id=1401179128",
        "extras":
            {"deeplink_context":"{\"promo_code\":\"testing\"}"},
        "referer_app_link":{"url":"fb:\/\/\/","app_name":"Facebook"}}, 
"$one_time_use": 0, "+match_guaranteed": 1, "$og_description": , 
"~id": 631024823602657926, 
"~creation_source": 1, 
"+click_timestamp": 1551695392, 
"~marketing": 1, 
"~campaign": reksadana, 
"~feature": ads, 
"~channel": facebook]
```

My question is, I want to parse the "promo_code" and it's value. How to do that? And as you can see in my code, there is switch case, which I hope I can put an event there. Anyone know how to solve this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you specify the exact issue? You are doing work to get the code.

Comment: @MuhammadZohaibEhsan I want to get the value of promo_code in {\"promo_code\":\"testing\"}"} and make a switch case from it

Comment: @FirdaSahidi, I could understand from the link that data passed under {"deeplink_context":"{\"promo_code\":\"testing\"}"}  is not a json object instead it's a string. You can pass in json object not as string. Other wise you need to handle it as a string.

Comment: If you still have any issue you can contact support@branch.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if let data =  al_appLink2.data(using: .utf8) {
do {
    let appLinkObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
            let extras = appLinkObject?["extras"] as? [String : Any]
            let promoCodeString = extras?["deeplink_context"] as? String
            if let promoString = promoCodeString, let data =  promoString.data(using: .utf8) {
                let promoCodeObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: String]
                let promoCode = promoCodeObject?["promo_code"]
                print(promoCode ?? "No Promo Code")
            }

        }
        catch(let error) {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}}
```

Try the above code. You have to get the "al_applink_data" first as a dictionary. Then get "extras" from it. Then the "deeplink_context" value. As value of "deeplink_context" is a string which represents a JSON string representation. Then you have to get the JSON object through JSON serialization and get the value of promo_code. I have made some edits for nil values.But make sure you test it properly. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help. It still not work in mine, "promoCode" doesn't printed. I also print al_appLink and extras, but the result is nil. Do you know why this happen and how to solve it?

Comment: can you check the values of params? what params["al_applink_data"] return in the debugger

Comment: "al_applink_data": {"target_url":"https:\/\/itunes.apple.com\/WebObjects\/MZStore.woa\/wa\/redirectToContent?id=1401179128","extras":{"deeplink_context":"{\"promo_code\":\"testestes\"}"}

Comment: It also looks like a string the value of "al_applink_data". You have to use json serialization and get the json object.

Comment: guard let al_appLink2 = data["al_applink_data"] as? String else { return } I use this and it's not nil, but I don't know how to access the extras. Do you know how to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189432/discussion-between-muhammad-zohaib-ehsan-and-firda-sahidi).

Comment: I have added the chat box in case you get further issues. Then we can continue there.